# How to implement a custom ScrollPhysics in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I would like to create a `CustomScrollPhysics` class extending `ScrollPhysics`.

I have read the source code but don't understand the description (translated from chinese)

> Whether the scrollable should let the user adjust the scroll offset,
>   for example by dragging. By default, the user can manipulate the
>   scroll offset if, and only if, there is actually content outside the
>   viewport to reveal.

Can someone help me understand the ScrollPhysics documentation?

---

*P.S.: I'm Chinese and I'm very poor in english.

P.P.S.: This question is edited as the OP feels his English is not very good*

Comment: Could you try the english version of the document https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics-class.html or better the actual code for ScrollPhysics https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_physics.dart?

Comment: @Amsakanna for example,I want to freeze the scrollable widget when i drag it to somewhere and it can scroll to top automatic if some event tigger.i don't know how to start code it.